# Проверка логинов пользователей Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Вы работаете над крупным интернет-сервисом с богатой историей. Требования к логину, который выбирает пользователь, уже много лет не меняются: логин должен содержать только буквы, цифры и символ подчёркивания «_». Однако с первых месяцев работы вашего сервиса в базе данных до сих пор остаётся «наследство»: «плохие» логины, не удовлетворяющие этим требованиям.
>
> Поскольку ваша компания заботится об интересах клиентов, отвечающий за эту проблему менеджер решил распечатать аккуратный список всех некорректных логинов и подумать над каждым из них, чтобы предложить обладателю этого логина наиболее подходящую замену. Составьте для менеджера аккуратно сформатированный список.
>
> ## Формат ввода
>
> Вводится одна строка: список всех зарегистрированных в системе логинов, разделённых запятыми (запятые не встречаются даже в «плохих» логинах).
>
> ## Формат вывода
>
> Выводятся все логины, не удовлетворяющие описанным в условии требованиям. Каждый логин выводится на отдельной строке. Порядок — алфавитный. Кроме того, логины должны быть выровнены пробелами по правому краю списка; ширина списка — наименьшая возможная, т. е. равна длине самого длинного из «плохих» логинов.
>   [image: Пример]

Не могу разобраться с задачей полностью

```
login = input().split(',')
bad = []
logs = []
length = []
for i in login:
    logs.append(i)
    length.append(len(i))
    f = False
    for e in i:
        condition = not (
            ord(e) >= ord('A') and ord(e) <= ord('z') 
            or ord(e) >= ord('0') and ord(e) <= ord('9') 
            or ord(e) >= ord('А') and ord(e) <= ord('я') 
            or ord(e) == ord('_')
        )  
        if condition:
            f = True
            break
    if f:
        bad.append(i)
bad.sort()
mx = max(length)
for i in bad:
    print(i.rjust(len(logs[length.index(mx)]), ' '))
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вводные данные и результат как текст

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регуляркой очень просто проверить наличие или отсутствие нужных символов:

```
import re

bad = []

for login in input().split(','):
    # Если встречается символ, отличающийся от букв, цифр и _
    if re.search('\W', login):
        bad.append(login)

# Если список не пустой
if bad:
    bad.sort()
    max_length = len(max(bad, key=len))

    for login in bad:
        print(login.rjust(max_length, ' '))
```

---

**PS.**

- `\w` - Буквенный или цифровой символ или знак подчёркивания
- `\W` - Любой символ, кроме буквенного или цифрового символа или знака подчёркивания